Measure to calculate date difference between action date and the date before
I have a table in power bi as below:



User id.
First date
Last date




X.
5 july 24
15 july 24


X.
15 jun 24
20 june 24


X.
3 apr 24
17 apr 24



I need a measure to calculate date difference between first date and previous last date
...i tried many measurea

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

you can try to create a column
Column =
VAR _last =
    MAXX (
        FILTER ( 'Table', 'Table'[Last date] < EARLIER ( 'Table'[Last date] ) ),
        'Table'[Last date]
    )
RETURN
    DATEDIFF ( _last, 'Table'[First date], DAY )


or create a measure
MEASURE =
VAR _last =
    MAXX (
        FILTER ( ALL ( 'Table' ), 'Table'[Last date] < MAX ( 'Table'[Last date] ) ),
        'Table'[Last date]
    )
RETURN
    DATEDIFF ( _last, MAX ( 'Table'[First date] ), DAY )


